# How to grep recursively in order of last modified time?

Tags: grep

`grep -r`  does a recursive search in all files in a particular directory. However, if I want these files to be read by grep in the order of their last modified time, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
grep -- foo **/*(D.om)
```

With GNU tools:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  sort -rg |
  cut -f2- |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  xargs -r0 grep foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have something like `zsh`, this isn't entirely trivial. It's probably more efficient to get the hits, then sort by the modification time of each file with a hit.

```
grep -rl 'regex' . |
while read -r file; do
    stat -c '%Y:%n' "$file"
done | sort | cut -d: -f2-
```

This will obviously break if you have file names with newlines on their names or something.